# What is the most performant way for dynamic styling in React-Native?

Tags: performance, react-native, dynamic, styles, stylesheet

In React-Native, you can use [Stylesheet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet) to create css-like stylesheets. The main reason of using `styleshee.create` in favor of plain js-objects is increased performance. However, you often might want to style components dynamically, often based on their props. I basically found three approaches of doing this:

***Note for the following examples:*** Consider `const styles ...` to be declared outside of the Component, as it's a common pattern and you might want to share styles between different Components. Consider everything below the tree dots as part of the render function.

1. Using an array of styles:

   ```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({viewStyle: {backgroundColor:'red'}})
   ...
   return <View style={[styles.viewStyle, {color: this.props.color}]} />
   ```
2. Using Stylesheet.flatten:

   ```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({viewStyle: {backgroundColor:'red'}})
   ...
   const flattenedStyle = StyleSheet.flatten(styles.viewStyle, {{color: this.props.color}})
   return <View style={flattenedStyle} />
   ```
3. Using a function to create the stylesheet:

   ```
   const styles = (color) => StyleSheet.create({
       viewStyle: {
           backgroundColor:'red',
           color: color
           }
       })
   ...
   const style = styles(this.props.color).viewStyle
   return <View style={style} />
   ```

I am wondering which approach is the best regarding to performance, or if there even is another, more performant way? I think Option 2 and 3 are no way to go at all, because dynamically creating new stylesheets on prop-changes undermines the whole purpose of stylesheets. I am happy for any thought or hints on this subject!

Comment: Have you found answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. In most cases I just use approach 1.

Comment: I also think the same that option two and three would take time and would make your code grow bigger 5 times faster than usual so i recommend using option one cause its simple, clean and easy to write 1000 times!

Comment: Here is an interesting topic about different styling options in React Native: https://medium.com/@alexeytsuts/choosing-the-technology-for-styles-in-react-native-104ef242bac7

Answer (score 4):

Here you can do dynamic styling in react native for each styling.

Like this

```
<Text style={styles.simpleText('red')}>Required field</Text>

// In styling
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     simpleText: (colorProp = 'black') => ({ // default black set
           fontSize: 14,
           color: colorProp,
     })
})
```

and you can also pass any data type for conditional styling

Answer (score 2):

One of the approach

```js
// homeSreen
<View style={styles.filterButton(isSelected)}>
  <Text> Strawberry </Text>
</View>

// styles.js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Colors } from '../../theme';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },

  filterButton: isSelected => ({
   padding: 15,
   backgroundColor: isSelected? Colors.background.primary: Colors.background.secondary
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could memoize stylesheet creation using React hooks, but first you need to do some performance checking in order to determine if stylesheet creation is in fact a CPU and/or memory hog worth optimizing.

Here's an example:

```
const styles = (color) => StyleSheet.create({
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor:'red',
        color: color
        }
    })

/*
even though makeStyle is defined in EVERY render,
React will only run it ONCE for any given props.color distinct value.
The resulting value `styles` survives re-renders
*/

const makeStyle = () => styles(props.color)
const styles = useMemo(makeStyle, [props.color]);
```

And here's the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

Comment: Current `StyleSheet.create` implementation is very fast and `useMemo` is okay. The question is it worth to use memoization (with not pure child component) or you can just create new object each render.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider CSS in JS libraries like `Styled components`?

You can pass props and get dynamic style regard that:

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Comment: It's inconceivable that such a complex library would give the best performance.  Best developer experience, sure, but that's not the question.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a bit overkill for simple dynamic styling but Reanimated is very performant and will run the style transition at 60fps https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated

It archives this by declaring all the styles needed for an animation/transition ahead of time and runs them on the native thread so there is minimal communication across the JS->Native code bridge.

There is a better explanation on their about page here https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/about